# html selected option in select differs of what I'm seeing in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dom, modal-dialog

In a django form, I have set the default option for a select. It is not showing those changes in UI, but after inspecting I'm seeing that the DOM is actually being changed. When I check in the console for the HTML, I can see that the selected option is set to 1, but when I ask jquery for the selected option it gives me another.

```
$("select[name=spread_format] option")
[<option value=​"0">​in.​</option>​, <option value=​"1" selected=​"selected">​ft.​</option>​]
$("select[name=spread_format] option:selected")
[<option value=​"0">​in.​</option>​]
$("select[name=spread_format]").val()
"0"
```

What I want to accomplish is to show 1 as default. This select is being rendered in a bootstrap modal.

Strange to notice that the selected option in UI is '0', not '1' as indicated my DOM.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the value of the selected option you should use `val()`, and not searching for the `<option>` element.

```js
$('#btn1').click(function() {
  console.log($('#s1').val());  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1">
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">B</option>
  <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
<br />
<button id="btn1">click</button>
```

Comment: thanks, now why am I not seeing the one that says selected, selected. The first option is the one displayed

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. In my example the selected option is "B", and the value there is 2.

Comment: I have added a screenshot with the issue. Selected in DOM is 1 but in UI is 0 @Dekel

Comment: The `selected` attribute will not change when changing the selected option on a `select` element (this is one of the reasons to work with `val()`).

Comment: val() is still returning a wrong value (0) and what I see in the UI differs of what I see in the DOM. I want to have 1 selected by default, this is OK in DOM but in UI is different. Take a look at the code I've updated

Comment: `val()` return the current selected value. If you changed your selection (from `.ft` to `.in`) `val()` will return the value of `.in` which is 0 (your `DOM` **will not** change due to the change of the `select` option)

Comment: thanks, I just realized that a javascript was changing the value.

Comment: Sure :) you are welcome. Please mark the answer as correct if it is.